# Can someone suggest an alternative way to request server['HTTPS']

Tags: php

I have installed OpenCarton on my website, and all is well until I tried to correctly set up SSL for secure areas.

I am currently making the site work by forcing https on for the whole site, but cannot get the secure pages to work when it is set up in the "correct" manner.

I am not an expert in php, so I hope you will treat as an *almost* idiot! I am learning as I go along.

I have researched through the OpenCart forum for a solution without success.

The problem is "insecure content" apparently occurring because the base href remains as http not https when visiting, for example, checkout.

I have already discovered that the likely cause is that my web host does not support the variable server['HTTPS'], they suggest asking OpenCart, but I have not got any useful answers there after nearly a week!

The following lines from /controller/common/header.php is where the problem lies.

```
    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
        $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
    } else {
        $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
    }
```

And again further down the file:

```
if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
        $server = HTTPS_IMAGE;
    } else {
        $server = HTTP_IMAGE;
    }
```

So what I need is another way to substitute these lines.

I have found some suggested alternatives in another post here for what looks like a similar problem, but I don't know hoe to implement them.

Step by step editing  would be helpful if someone has the patience.

I can give more info if needed but didn't want to go too far too soon.

Thanks

Robin

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($this->request->server('SERVER_PORT')) && (($this->request->server('SERVER_PORT') == '443'))) {
    $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
} else {
    $this->data['base'] = $this->config->get('config_url');
}
```

and do the same for your other snippet of code. You basically check to see what port the server is running on. HTTP will be served on port 80 and HTTPS will be on port 443.

Comment: btw if the 443 does not work then echo out $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] when on an HTTPS connection to see what port it's set to. The default is 443, but some hosts may have it at another value from the norm.

Comment: Sorry to say, @cryptic , but it has not worked! Still getting base href as http not https.

Comment: Oop sorry again @cryptic I hadn't seen your edit. Can you tell me how to " echo out $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']" ?

Comment: Ah-ha! I think I am at a dead end, because the service I use uses proxy server, so I think all I can do is set the whole site to https, rather than normal secure areas only? If you can confirm this, I will stop wasting everyone's time!

Comment: @user1888391 Sorry I must have missed your comment in my inbox. To echo out the port do this: echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; when you are on HTTPS then change the '443' in above code to that port if it is different and that code will work correctly then. Would it be possible for you to post the link to the site so I can check the ports/ips for HTTP and HTTPS to see if this code will work even if site uses proxy?

Comment: @user1888391, I feel so stupid I had an obvious typo in my code. I was accessing via array index that is not the way it should be accessed. Please try the update.